Making an overload take effect only if no same overloads exist already
I want to make a simple ostream& operator << overload, but I don't want any ambiguity errors from the compiler if there so happens to be another overload.
Here is the closest thing I could think of:
template<class Collection>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const Collection& other)
    requires requires () {
    requires not requires() {stream << other;};//errors here
    other.begin() != other.end();
    ++other.begin();
    stream << *other.begin();

} {...}

The problem with the code above is that the compiler produces the following error:
1. Satisfaction of constraint 'requires { requires !requires { stream << other; }; }' depends on itself [constraint_depends_on_self]

What I want is to make a generic overload for any collection to be easily outputed to the console (for debugging purposes), but some collections like std::string already have an overload, so a call to something like std::ostream << std::string is ambiguous.
A simple way to mitigate the problem is to prohibit the overload for std::string specifically, but I'm curious if it is possible to make a solution for all existing overloads, not just one specific one.
I'm using C++20 (I don't mind C++23 solutions) clang and gcc compilers, if that matters.
P.S. Please, do not suggest using a wrapper or a differently named function / operator. This is not solving the problem, this is avoiding it.

Normally C++ will take the "most specific" overload (and consider templated functions last). So if you want an overload for collections you will need to speficy constraints on the Collection being iterable (very losely defined).  And maybe constrain you other template to not work on non-iterable classes.

Yeah, I had a constraint on iteratability, but removed it in the question. I see now it was a mistake to do so.
The problem is, std::string is iteratable and there is an overload for it within the standard library already. I will edit the questions to include the constraints you mentioned.

@DiKetarogg "but removed it in the question. I see now it was a mistake to do so" -- Not entirely a mistake. All you're missing is a comment like /* Other requirements omitted */.

Better that the template function has at least one of your own types.

There's a saying that many problems can be solved with another layer of abstraction. Have you tried to define a regular function (not operator<<) that has the desired functionality/requirements?

The simple way to solve this is to not overload the operator for types you don't own and instead write a named function that will do the operation.  You might be able to write a concept for a non-streamable container and then change the function to be like template<non_streamable_collection Colection> std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const Collection& other) { ... } but I'm not sure how that will interact

"Have you tried to define a regular function (not operator<<) that has the desired functionality?" It would work, of course, given that there are no other overloads, but is less convenient to use a specific function like this.

Making a concept that checks for non streamable types yields the same error.

@DiKetarogg Thanks for confirming, I had a feeling it would but wasn't sure.

Use another named function, or "wrap" either the stream or the collection.

"Please, do not suggest using a wrapper or a differently named function / operator. This is not solving the problem, this is avoiding it." Why must you use << without any wrapping? It's really easy to make something that wraps everything

@Caleth Because I don't want to see code like std::cout << my_wrapper(some_vector); in my source files. If it is not possible to implement what I want through requirements, I will do so through other means. I want my code to have no extra phrases that make it overly verbose. Wrappers should only be used in making tools, not in using them (unless it improves readability, which it doesn't in this case).

Right. Imo clang is morally right to complain, because you are changing the result of a concept as part of using it.

Even if it was possible, allowing std::cout << some_vector; might lead to ODR violation (or same problem you have with std::string) when/if standard add an overload for std::vector. That's why template functions (and especially operator) should have at least one user-type.

@Caleth Sure, it is. It was what I came up with to demonstrate what I intend to happen. Compilers do not know what I want, but humans can deduce the meaning. The question is not about whether the error is righteous or not, after all. However, if you want to discuss whether clang is 'morally right', please do so in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78409313/function-being-considered-in-overload-resolution-when-evaluating-its-own-require](this question).

@Jarod42 If some sort of requirement is used, multiple functions with the same arguments should not be created and therefore no ODR violations should happen, I think.
If the standard adds a overload for std::vector, the custom overload should be able to account for that and not allow std::vector as an argument (through constrains or other means), so that the standard version is used.

The easiest way would be to define two concepts:

Iterable
Streamable

And then you have to write your template and require to satisfy the constraint Iterable<T> && !Streamable<T>.
For instance:
template <typename T>
concept Iterable = requires(T t)
{
    t.cbegin();
    t.cend();
};

template <typename T>
concept Streamable = requires(std::ostream & os, T t)
{
    operator<<(os, t);
};

template <typename Collection>
requires (Iterable<Collection> && not Streamable<Collection>)
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Collection & c)
{
    os << '{';
    for(auto cit = c.cbegin(); cit < c.cend(); ++cit)
    {
        if(cit != c.cbegin())
            os << ", ";
        os << *cit;
    }
    os << "}\n";
    return os;
}

This way your overload will be used only for iterable types for which the operator<<() is not already provided.
Live example

Yes, we tried that. It yields the same error (at least, with my compiler anyway).

@DiKetarogg It works with GCC but not with clang :/ I need to investigate on that

That's funny, because my clang compiler does not complain, but gcc does. Also, my clangd server also complains.

@DiKetarogg I observe the opposite but it is strange that clang tries to use the current definition when evaluating its own constraint.

Oh yeah, gcc works on my machine. My bad, I mixed the two.
clang complains.

@DiKetarogg I posted a question about this issue.

I think I figured out how to solve the issue.
Try operator<<(os, t), instead of os << t.
I'd love to hear explanations as to why this works though.

@DiKetarogg It's very strange... seems like a clang bug for me. You were the one coming with a question, now I'm the one left with lots of interrogations :D Anyway I'm glad you found a solution !

Well, it seems, the answer doesn't really work if more overloads are added afterwards. So my guess, it's just impossible.
https://godbolt.org/z/MMrn3T8Mb

@DiKetarogg Actually, it's up to the implementer to provide the operator<<() overload for his/her own type. Trying to provide a default implementation for types you don't own seems like going out of your scope/overdoing things/stepping over other's toes. And if someone wants to define a class that must not be "streamable", you're shooting them in the foot :)

which is why I have (for debugging purposes) clarification in my question.
Though, I can't come up with any example as to why you wouldn't want a class to be streamable, given that it is iteratable over streamable elements.
