Function being considered in overload resolution when evaluating its own requirements
This question is a follow-up for the solution provided here where the OP wanted to provide an output stream operator implementation (operator<<()) for any generic collection for which it is not already defined.
For completeness and to make this question self-contained, here is the proposed solution (and a small test in the main()):
template <typename T>
concept Iterable = requires(T t)
{
    t.cbegin();
    t.cend();
};

template <typename T>
concept Streamable = requires(std::ostream & os, T t)
{
    os << t;
};

template <typename Collection>
requires (Iterable<Collection> && not Streamable<Collection>)
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Collection & c)
{
    os << '{';
    for(auto cit = c.cbegin(); cit < c.cend(); ++cit)
    {
        if(cit != c.cbegin())
            os << ", ";
        os << *cit;
    }
    os << "}\n";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s("FooBar -> ");
    std::vector<int> v {1, 5, 8};

    std::cout << s;
    std::cout << v; // <---------- Fails with clang !

    return 0;
}


error: satisfaction of constraint '!Streamable<Collection>' depends on itself

And here is a live example illustrating the issue: Live example of the issue
The proposed solution seems to work on gcc but fails with clang. Surprisingly, it seems that clang tries to use the overload for which we are evaluating the constraint in the candidates (which does not make sense to me).
I'm wondering which one is right according to the standard ?

Edit:
If I replace with an explicit operator<<(os, t); instead of os << t; in the requirements of the Streamable concept, clang finally accepts it as well.

Always post complete error along with your question.

Collection might be streamable if it is not streamable... Say in other way, evaluating Streamable<Collection> might lead to 2 different results...

Interestingly, using Streamable<std::vector<int>> before defining that << makes clang accept it

Why is the compiler checking this concept and generating an error?

This can't be done with concepts (they are never instanciated), but it can be accomplished with a constexpr variable - see Is it ok to define a function using SFINAE that requires non-existance of the function?
